# How do get param from a url

Tags: javascript, jquery

As seen below I'm trying to get #currentpage to pass client params

Can someone help out thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.addEventListener("load", windowLoaded, false);
    function windowLoaded() {
      chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        document.getElementById('currentpage').innerHTML = tab.url;
      });
    }
    var url = $("currentpage");
    // yes I relize this is the part not working.
    var client = jQuery.param("currentpage");
    var page = jQuery.param("currentpage");
    var devurl = "http://#/?clientsNumber=" + client + "&pageName=" + page ;
});
```

Comment: But what exactly is this code trying to accomplish?

Comment: You should take more time when creating a title for your questions, as is, it's not even close to asking the right question. A better question is: `How do I extract query string variables from a url?`

Comment: Why are you storing the url as the innerHTML of a node?

Comment: `url = $("currentpage");` What does that mean? Earlier you write `document.getElementById('currentpage')`. If you want to get the element with the ID currentpage with jQuery it's `url = $("#currentpage");`

Comment: Do you mean "$("#currentpage").html() = ?c=231171&p=irol-irhome&dc=107545"?  If so, then @JuanMendes is correct, and you need to use a completely different method to serialize the url parameters.

Answer (score 2):

This is a method to extract the params from a url

```
function getUrlParams(url) {
  var paramMap = {};
  var questionMark = url.indexOf('?');
  if (questionMark == -1) {
    return paramMap;
  }
  var parts = url.substring(questionMark + 1).split("&");

  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i ++) {
    var component = parts[i].split("=");
    paramMap [decodeURIComponent(component[0])] = decodeURIComponent(component[1]);
  }
  return paramMap;
}
```

Here's how to use it in your code

```
var url =  "?c=231171&p=home";
var params = getUrlParams(url);
var devurl = "http://site.com/?c=" + encodeURIComponent(params.c) + "&p=" + encodeURIComponent(params.p) + "&genphase2=true";
// devurl == "http://site.com/?c=231171&p=home&genphase2=true"
```

See it in action http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/TCpsD/

Here's the code you posted with minimal changes to get it working, it also uses `$.param` as it's intended, that is to create a query string from a JS object, this works well since my suggested function returns an object from the url

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This does not handle arrays because it's not part of the official specs
    // PHP and some other server side languages support it but there's no official
    // consensus
    function getUrlParams(url) {
      var paramMap = {};
      var questionMark = url.indexOf('?');
      if (questionMark == -1) {
        return paramMap;
      }
      var parts = url.substring(questionMark + 1).split("&");

      for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i ++) {
        var component = parts[i].split("=");
        paramMap [decodeURIComponent(component[0])] = decodeURIComponent(component[1]);
      }
      return paramMap;
    }
    // no need for the extra load listener here, jquery.ready already puts 
    // your code in the onload
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        document.getElementById('currentpage').innerHTML = tab.url;
    });

    var url = $("currentpage");
    var paramMap = getUrlParams(url);
    // Add the genphase parameter to the param map
    paramMap.genphase2 = true;

    // Use jQuery.param to create the url to click on
    var devurl = "http://site.com/?"+ jQuery.param(paramMap);
    $('#mydev').click( function(){
        window.open(devurl);
    });
});
```

Comment: Aha, yes. I see.  The original poster was trying to serialize the url using $.param, when $.param is meant to serialize a DOM object.

Comment: @Dave: You see... but the answer doesn't deserve an upvote? :)

Comment: Still waiting to see if that was the actual question.

Comment: @Blynn: How would you serialize what? Your example looks like you're trying to take query string variables and put them into another url, which is exactly what my code does.

Comment: @Blynn: You changed the title to match what I suggested but you didn't mark this answer as correct. Which part are you still missing? I added a new example that is exactly like what you posted but now should work as intended